# Azure ML: How to train a model on multiple instances

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have a AML compute cluster with the min & max nodes set to 2. When I execute a pipeline, I expect the cluster to run the training on both instances in parallel. But the cluster status reports that only one node is busy and the other is idle.

Here's my code to submit the pipeline, as you can see, I'm resolving the cluster name and passing that to my Step1, thats training a model on Keras.

```
aml_compute = AmlCompute(ws, "cluster-name")
step1 = PythonScriptStep(name="train_step",
                         script_name="Train.py", 
                         arguments=["--sourceDir", os.path.realpath(source_directory) ],
                         compute_target=aml_compute, 
                         source_directory=source_directory,
                         runconfig=run_config,
                         allow_reuse=False)
pipeline_run = Experiment(ws, 'MyExperiment').submit(pipeline1, regenerate_outputs=False)
```

Comment: can you explain why you need to run distributed training? there's significant complexity introduced when you go from training on one machine to 2+ machines.

Comment: TBH, In my work, I've never had a dataset large enough to justify distributed training, and even if I did, I would try and exhaust alternatives to distributed training (e.g. sampling) before I bit the bullet on the extra complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each python script step runs on a single node even if you allocate multiple nodes in your cluster. I'm not sure whether training on different instances is possible off-the-shelf in AML, but there's definitely the possibility to use that single node more effectively (looking into using all your cores, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Really great question. The `TL;DR` is that there isn't an easy way to do that right now. IMHO there's a few questions within your questions -- here's a stab at all of them.

### Distributed Training with `keras`

I'm no `keras` expert, but from [their distributed training guide](https://keras.io/guides/distributed_training/), I'm interested to know about the `parallelism` that you are after? model parallelism or data parallelism?

For data parallelism, it looks like the `tf.distribute` API is the way to go. I would strongly recommend getting that working on a single, multi-GPU machine (local or Azure VM) without Azure ML before starting to use Pipelines.

### Distributed training with Azure ML

[This Azure ML notebook](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/ml-frameworks/pytorch/training/distributed-pytorch-with-horovod/distributed-pytorch-with-horovod.ipynb) shows how to use PyTorch with Horovod on AzureML. Seems not too tricky to change this to [work with `keras`](https://horovod.readthedocs.io/en/stable/keras.html#).

As for how to get distributed training to work inside of an Azure ML Pipeline, one spitball workaround would be to have the `PythonScriptStep` be a controller that would create a new compute cluster and submit the training script to it. I'm not too confident but I'll do some digging.

### Multi-Node `PythonScripSteps`

This is possible (at least w/ `pyspark`). Below is a `PythonScriptStep` a production pipeline of ours that can run on more than one node. It uses a Docker image with Spark pre-installed, and a `pyspark` `RunConfiguration`. In the screenshots below you can see one of the nodes is the primary orchestrator, and the other is a secondary worker.

```py
from azureml.core import Environment, RunConfiguration

env = Environment.from_pip_requirements(
    'spark_env',
    os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'compute', 'spark-requirements.txt'))
env.docker.enabled = True
env.docker.base_image = 'microsoft/mmlspark:0.16'
spark_run_config = RunConfiguration(framework="pyspark")
spark_run_config.environment = spark_env
spark_run_config.node_count = 2

roll_step = PythonScriptStep(
    name='roll.py',
    script_name='roll.py',
    arguments=['--input_dir', joined_data,
                '--output_dir', rolled_data],
    compute_target=compute_target_spark,
    inputs=[joined_data],
    outputs=[rolled_data],
    runconfig=spark_run_config,
    source_directory=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'compute', 'roll'),
    allow_reuse=pipeline_reuse
)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the detailed and elaborate response. As of now my dataset is a few hundred MB and it takes ~4hrs to train. I was hoping to cut this down by horizontally scaling the training nodes. I'm gonna to see if I can play with this. Thanks again!

Comment: Hmmm. 400MB doesn't strike me as _very_ large... what VM size are you using? Also,
 I'd recommend seeing what you can get done using distributed methods on a single machine. We had a `PythonScriptStep` that took over 90 minutes to run with `pandas` (which can only run single core). We ported it to `pyspark` and it runs in 12 minutes now on a single node (but now multi-core and highly optimized). If you get a single-core, distributed-`keras`  `PythonScriptStep`, I've love to see what you cooked up (so would the Azure ML product team, I imagine).